# Why does container div insist on being slightly larger than IMG or SVG content?

Tags: css

I'm trying to produce yet another lightbox as much needed HTML/CSS/Javascript practice, but I've encountered a styling issue that looks trivial (and probably is!) but I just can't solve it.

I have a `div` that contains an `img`. No matter what I try (`border`, `margin`, `padding`, auto height etc.) I just can't make the `div` shrink to match the image dimensions. I've reduced the problem to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <title>Layout experiments</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #lightbox {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position    : fixed;
                left        : 50%;
                margin-left : -320px;
                top         : 100px;
                border-radius: 22px;
                background  : #e0e0f0;
                color       : #102020;
            }

            #lightbox img {
                border-radius: 15px;
            }
            .imagebg {
                margin      : 7px;
                background  : black;
                border-radius: 15px;
                height      : 100%;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="lightbox">
            <div class="imagebg">
                <img src="picture.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

'picture.jpg' is 640x400, but the container div wants to be 640x404, the difference showing itself as a black strip below the image. The div exists so that I can fade the image to black by blending it's opacity down to 0, swap it, then blend it back in.

I've looked at the computed styles in multiple browsers and can't see where the 4px delta is coming from.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Trying adding:

```
img { display: block; }
```

to your CSS. Since an `<img>` is an inline element by default, its height is calculated differently as related to the default line-height value.

On inline elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

On block level elements, line-height specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height

Comment: That does indeed fix it. Could you elaborate as to why it makes a difference? (I'm not holding out on accepting - SO won't let me until 11 more minutes have passed)

Comment: @Chris - it's the reason I had given you: the `img` has an implicit `line-height` assigned to it, which gives it some vertical breathing room. Since `line-height` only applies to `inline` elements, setting the `img` to `display: block` removes the `line-height`.

Comment: @Joseph - I hadn't seen your response when I made the above request. Since they are basically achieving the exact same thing directly and indirectly, there's not much to choose between the answers. It only seems fair to accept the answer that arrived first, but thanks for your explanation.

Comment: This also works with `inline-block`. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 31):

Your image is using the line-height of its parent. Try this:

```
.imagebg { line-height: 0 }
```

Answer (score 15):

try adding:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

This is used in google material design lite for removing the gap between audio, canvas, iframes, images, videos and the bottom of their containers.

Material Design Lite: https://getmdl.io

Github discusion: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440

Comment: The accepted solution changes the display, which in my case wasn't desirable. This worked for me without any drawbacks.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from other working answers, setting `display` property of parent to `flex` worked for me as well:

```
.imagebg { display: flex }
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically you are getting this error on IE, though you hve not mentioned but this is the fact. IE generates some extra space below the `<img>` tag. Hence its a good practice to make the images `img { display: block; }`.

EDIT: You can say its a bug of IE

Comment: I didn't mention IE because I am not using it. Safari, Chrome and Firefox all demonstrate the same behaviour. Both Joseph and sbeliv01's answers work.

Comment: It is not a bug of IE. All <img> are vertically aligned by baseline by default. (vertical-align: baseline), which means their lowest point is aligned with the font's baseline (lowest point of the circle in the letter 'p', for example).

To change this, you only need to set a different way of aligning it, for example, vertical-align: top; or vertical-align: bottom;. There's no need to turn <img> into a block element, as its inherent inline properties might be useful.

Answer (score -5):

If you don't want to change `display` of the element, try

```
margin-bottom: -4px;
```