# Element aligned below bottom = 0px

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a card with an image and some text at its bottom.

```
<div href="#" class="card">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x150">
    <span>Events</span>
</div>
```

The css is currently as follows.

```
div.card
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
    div.card span
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 2;

        width: 100%;

        background-color: #000000;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

The problem I have is that the span is aligned a few pixels below the actual image, as can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/fe7Luaa6/ . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>As you can see by [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7Luaa6/1/), the `div.card` is a little taller than 150px (the height of the image).</strike>

If you explicitly set the height of the `<div>` to the height of the image like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7Luaa6/2/), this will be solved.

---

Actually, an easier way (as suggested by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11126701/2397327)), says that this is because the `<img>` is, by default, an `inline-block` element and this causes the height of the container `<div>` to be calculated a little differently.

Adding a simple `img { display: block; }` will be an easier way to solve this, as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7Luaa6/3/).

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that the image I'm adding is not always the same height.

Comment: @StefanSchouten See my new solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I'll mark it as answer in 5 minutes! I've tried a lot but forgot this.

Comment: @StefanSchouten I'm glad I helped!

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the revision.  I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @StefanSchouten Thanks for marking my answer in five minutes =P ... just a gentle reminder

Comment: Whoops! Haha, I'm sorry, I left for home after that and indeed forgot it! But it's done :)